# Are there any words or terms when 'a small daughter dancing with her dad with her feet on top of his'?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, american-english, slang

[image: barefoot girl's feet on her father's shoes]

I'm writing my story and I had the idea to have both the characters to dance with one of them standing on the other's feet. But whenever I tried to search the word or term nothing showed up. The only thing that helped the description are stock photos but even the names don't have anything.  So does anybody here know it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt there is a single word. "Dancing... [her] feet on [his] feet" is a clear and widely used expression for this:

> I have her hands in mine, and we waddle around the room, father and daughter, hand in hand, and feet on feet. —[The Lie: A Story of Love](https://books.google.com/books?id=_5amDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT174&dq=hand%20in%20hand%20%22feet%20on%20feet%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjcgenCuPHwAhVVXM0KHe9lCOQQ6AEwBnoECAwQAw)

> When she was younger her dad taught the girls how to two-step by dancing with him with their feet on his feet. —[Anna Huson Obituary](https://www.leadertelegram.com/obituaries/anna-huson/article_f0910ac5-a323-515a-941a-57f647e131be.html)

> He would hold my hands tight, tell me to place my little feet on his feet, and then he would easily move his feet around. —[Treasured Memories - Dancing feet](https://www.wattpad.com/amp/766704937)

Comment: OP essentially has this in the question. Is it really ELU level?